# How to include Amazon MWS client library in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, amazon-mws

I downloaded Amazon MWS Library from official Amazon developer portal (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts). I added this lib in

**root/libraries**

I create the contorller **Amazon.php**

```
public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library('MarketplaceWebServiceProducts');
}
```

**Unable to load the requested class: MarketplaceWebServiceProducts**

How can I include this script in CodeIgniter?

Thanks...

Comment: in Amazon.php use include(APPPATH . 'libraries/<path to the aws library') before class definition.

Comment: May be rename the filename and class to `Marketplacewebserviceproducts.php` and the `class Marketplacewebserviceproducts {}` first letter only upper case. Then `$this->load->library('marketplacewebserviceproducts');`

Comment: @dido i am also facing same issue if you have find any solution please help me